# Apear error when uploading files with php

Tags: php

I have this code that i use to upload files on the server. But I get a custom Error produced by else statement,but I need to know the real reason why php is unable to upload the file. 
I Get error 2 but I dont get the actual message.
Any suggestions?

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path."/")) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! ".$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'];
        }
```

Comment: Turn on error_reporting. `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and look in your logs.  Or turn on `display_errors` for development.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form. Thanx

Comment: whats the error code reported by $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] ?

Comment: @themhz A good idea to always develop with display_errors turned on and error_reporting cranked up to E_ALL|E_STRICT.

Comment: yep, I just realized this, since I got my head bumping for some hours now. Thanx Michael

Comment: @AngelWorkz the error is 2 as Code. I don't see the full message

Comment: you can check http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php for detailed error messages. 2 is for The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form

Comment: @AngelWorkz yes this is the error, but I can only see in the error logs the message. Is it possible to show this message in runtime like $_FILES['uploadedfile']['errormessage'] or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for actual error occured

```
  $upload_errors = array(
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK        => "No errors.", 
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE    => "Larger than upload_max_filesize.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    => "Larger than form MAX_FILE_SIZE.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL    => "Partial upload.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE        => "No file.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR    => "No temporary directory.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE    => "Can't write to disk.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION     => "File upload stopped by extension.",
    UPLOAD_ERR_EMPTY        => "File is empty." // add this to avoid an offset
  );
   // error: report what PHP says went wrong
   $err =  $upload_errors[$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']];

   echo $err;
```

Comment: I was looking for this actualy. I just created the function in my controler. So there is no way that php can produce the message, only the error code and then use a custom function for those messages.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why your adding a directory separator on the end of the destination parameter `$target_path."/"`.

removing it or replacing with `$target_path.basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])` should do the trick.

```
<?php 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again! ".$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'];
}
?>
```

Comment: thanx, but for small files it works. My problem is that i need to get the actual error message to be displayd in runtime